# Angular.forEach only affects last row

Tags: angularjs

Been trying to rap my head around this all day. Hopefully some new eyes can get it!!!

Basically I have a scope: gridOrder which contains (ProdID: & Quantity:). I am using the product ID to get data from DB (Quantity & Reserved Quantity).

I then pass this onto a function which calculates some data and adds the required data to another scope called prodOrder[]. prodOrder is given the same index as the equivalent gridOrder (i.e if gridOrder[2] then prodOrder[2] is created).

It all works fine if I work chronologically, as in gridOrder[0], then gridOrder[1] but if I am on gridOrder[x] and go back to gridOrder[x-a] (a>1) it will not update the values on gridOrder[x-a].

If anyone can offer any insight it would be much appreciated.

**code now working**

```
 $scope.reservedStockFunction = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.gridOrder, function(value, key){
            $scope.rvalue = value;
            $scope.rkey = key;
            console.log(value);console.log(key);
            //Check stock. 
            var reservedStockRequest = {prodID: value.prodID, prod_quantity: "", prod_reserved_quantity: "", table: "products"};
            //Send requst
            search_given_where.request(reservedStockRequest).success(function(data){
                updValues(data, key, value);
            });
        }); 
        function updValues(data, key, value){
            console.log(data);
            var i = key; 
            if (typeof $scope.prodOrder[i] == "undefined" || !($scope.prodOrder[i] instanceof Array)) {
                $scope.prodOrder[i] = {};
            }           
            //Set Quantity variable.
            if (value.quantity !== undefined){
                var qty = value.quantity;
            } else {
                var qty = 0;
            }
            //Set Product Quanity Variable.
            var prodQty = data[0].prod_quantity;
            //Set Reserved Product Quantity variable.
            var prodRsvdQty = data[0].prod_reserved_quantity;
            //Reserved quantity = current reserved quantity + quantity.
            prodRsvdQty = +prodRsvdQty + +qty;
            //If reserved quantity is greater than stock.
            if(prodRsvdQty > prodQty){
                var reservedStockMessage = "Product:" + value.prodID + "  Stock:" + prodQty + "  Reserved Stock:" + prodRsvdQty;
                //Let user know.
                $scope.reservedStockMessage[i] = {};
                $scope.reservedStockMessage[i].message = reservedStockMessage;
                //Show reserved stock options.
                $scope.reservedStock.show = true;
                //Create array to update product table.
                $scope.prodOrder[i].prodID= value.prodID;
                $scope.prodOrder[i].prod_reserved_quantity = prodRsvdQty;
                $scope.prodOrder[i].reserved = 1;
                //Set reserved on gridOrder array.
                value.reserved="1";
                data = null;
                key = null;
                value = null;
                qty = null;
                prodQty = null;
                prodRsvdQty = null;
            //If not.
            } else if (prodRsvdQty < prodQty){
                $scope.reservedStockMessage[i] = {};
                //Create array to update product table.
                $scope.prodOrder[i].prodID= value.prodID;
                $scope.prodOrder[i].prod_reserved_quantity = prodRsvdQty;
                $scope.prodOrder[i].reserved = 0;
                //Set Reserved on gridOrder array.
                value.reserved="0";
                data = null;
                key = null;
                value = null;
                qty = null;
                prodQty = null;
                prodRsvdQty = null;
            }
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh, you're using wrong the parameters for the callback updValues.

Could you try to use:

```
search_given_where.request(reservedStockRequest).success(function(data){
    updValues(data, key, value);
});
```

To use scoped values from key and value.

Comment: Amazing, I tried this to no avail, tried again at your request and all is perfect so far!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you need, you could read about javascript closures: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-closures-demystified/, specially about closure problems with loops.